# Python mypy marks error when method parameter is type Union

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, mypy, concreteclass

I have these python classes:

```
class LocalWritable(typing.TypedDict):
    file_name: str


class GSheetWritable(typing.TypedDict):
    tab_name: str


class S3Writable(typing.TypedDict):
    data_name: str
    table_name: str


WriterMeta = typing.Union[GSheetWritable, S3Writable, LocalWritable]

class DataWriter(ABC):
    """Defines the interface for all data writers"""

    @abstractmethod
    def write(self, data: pd.DataFrame, meta: WriterMeta, versionize: bool):
        """This method performs the writing of 'data'.

        Every class implementing this method must implement its writing
        using 'connector'
        """
        pass

class GSheetOutputWriter(DataWriter):
    def write(self, data: pd.DataFrame, meta: WriterMeta, versionize: bool):
        data = data.replace({np.nan: 0, np.Inf: "Inf"})

        print("Writing '{}' table to gsheet.".format(meta["tab_name"]))
        if self.new:
            tab = self.connector.get_worksheet(self.target.url, "Sheet1")
            self.connector.rename_worksheet(tab, meta["tab_name"])
            self.new = False
        else:
            tab = self.connector.add_worksheet(
                self.target, meta["tab_name"], rows=1, cols=1
            )

        time.sleep(random.randint(30, 60))
        self.connector.update_worksheet(
            tab, [data.columns.values.tolist()] + data.values.tolist()
        )
```

The problem is with the method `write()` when linting with **python mypy**, because it marks this error:

```
cost_reporter\outputs\__init__.py:209: error: TypedDict "S3Writable" has no key "tab_name"
cost_reporter\outputs\__init__.py:209: note: Did you mean "table_name" or "data_name"?
cost_reporter\outputs\__init__.py:209: error: TypedDict "LocalWritable" has no key "tab_name"
```

What I am trying to do is to implement three concrete classes based on the abstract class `DataWriter`, and each one shall implement its own `write()` method and each one shall receive one of the datatypes of `WriterMeta` union. The problem I am having is that **python mypy** validates the code against the three datatypes instead of any of them.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

If I change the type of parameter `meta` to `GsheetWritable`(that is one of the three types of the union and the one expected by this concrete class), **mypy** marks this error:

```
cost_reporter\outputs\__init__.py:202: error: Argument 2 of "write" is incompatible with supertype "DataWriter"; supertype defines the argument type as "Union[GSheetWritable, S3Writable, LocalWritable]"
cost_reporter\outputs\__init__.py:202: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
```

Comment: since the problem is with `write`, is it possible to simplify your example and remove the rest? It will be much easier to answer like that

Comment: @joel Done, I made the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Union` works like unions in set theory. In other words, a `Union` consisting of multiple types is a type that supports **only what's shared in common.**

In order to use attributes (or whatever) of a specific type, you need to hint to mypy that you're constraining an instance. You can do this by casting the `Union` to a specific type, `assert`ing that your object *is* whatever specific type, and others. The [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html) lists ways to narrow types.

```py
import typing
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class LocalWritable(typing.TypedDict):
    file_name: str


class GSheetWritable(typing.TypedDict):
    tab_name: str


class S3Writable(typing.TypedDict):
    data_name: str
    table_name: str


WriterMeta = typing.Union[GSheetWritable, S3Writable, LocalWritable]


class DataWriter(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def write(self, data: str, meta: WriterMeta):
        pass


class GSheetOutputWriter(DataWriter):
    def write(self, data: str, meta: WriterMeta):
        # LOOK HERE! The cast hints to mypy that meta is a GSheetWritable.
        meta_cast: GSheetWritable = typing.cast(GSheetWritable, meta)
        print("Writing '{}' table to gsheet.".format(meta_cast["tab_name"]))
```

### Further reading

- [Type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html)
- [Union type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)